# subclassing boost exception

Tags: c++, exception, boost, subclass

I have a custom exception class that inherits from `boost::exception` as follows:

```
class ConfigurationException : public boost::exception
{
public:
    ConfigurationException(const std::string & title, const std::string & message) {
        QMessageBox box(QMessageBox::Critical, QString::fromStdString(title), QString::fromStdString( parse(message) ), QMessageBox::Ok);
        box.exec();
    }
}
```

and it can be called from code like this:

```
try {
   // Do some stuff here
} catch (std::exception e) {
    BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION( ConfigurationException("Configuration Error", e.what()) );
}
```

However, when I try to compile, I get the errors

```
Libs\boost\include\boost/throw_exception.hpp(58): error C2664:'boost::throw_exception_assert_compatibility' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const ConfigurationException' to 'const std::exception &'
          Reason: cannot convert from 'const ConfigurationException' to 'const std::exception'
          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
          Libs\boost\include\boost/throw_exception.hpp(85) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::throw_exception<E>(const E &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              E=ConfigurationException
          ]
          src\ConfigurationReader.cpp(81) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::exception_detail::throw_exception_<ConfigurationException>(const E &,const char *,const char *,int)' being compiled
          with
          [
              E=ConfigurationException
          ]
```

I'm not really sure why it's trying to cast my exception to an `std::exception`. Can someone tell me how I can throw this exception and get the file, function etc. data too? (I should say obviously that `throw ConfigurationException("some title", "some message");` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Derive from both `std::exception` and `boost::exception` *virtually*: `struct ConfigurationException : virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception`.
2. Catch by const reference: `catch (const std::exception& e)`.
3. Don't put GUI logic in an exception constructor. Put it in an exception handler (i.e. `catch` block).
4. Consider using `error_info` to attach additional information (like your title and message).

And in general, be careful when mixing Qt with exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you perhaps elaborate on your point about mixing Qt with exceptions? Could you suggest a better way to deploy a message to notify a user of a corrupt configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION calls boost::throw_exception, which requires that the exception object derives from std::exception (see www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/exception/doc/throw_exception.html). The compile error enforces that requirement.

Another thing, catch exceptions by reference. Don't catch(std::exception e), catch( std::exception & e ) instead.